# google analytics metric ga:users pre and post 2016

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Evening,

While coding a javascript using Google analytics API to display data on a backoffice. I stumble around a weird problem related to the ga:users metric.

I have a graph that displays ga:users and ga:pageviews for a given year. And a select box with various years since the site was launched.

It runs this code

```
            reportChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
                query: {
                    'ids': 'ga:6XXXXXXX',
                    'start-date': '2015-01-01',
                    'end-date': '2015-12-31',
                    'metrics': 'ga:users,ga:pageviews',
                    'dimensions': 'ga:date'
                },
                chart: {
                    'container': 'graficoIndex',
                    'type': 'LINE',
                    'options': {
                        'width': '100%',
                        'height': '230px'
                    }
                }
            });

            reportData = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
                query: {
                    'ids': 'ga:6XXXXXXX',
                    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews, ga:users, ga:sessions, ga:percentNewSessions, ga:pageviewsPerSession',
                    'dimensions': 'ga:date',
                    'start-date': '2015-01-01',
                    'end-date': '2015-12-31'
                }
            });

        reportChart.execute();

        reportData.execute();
```

And on select box change I just execute a different query and chart with the new start-date and end-date.

Now to the problem: all seems fine after 22 of August 2016 but before that the metric ga:users is always zero.

Going to the Query explorer at https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ I confirmed this getting zero for ga:users from 01/01/2014 to 31/12/2014 (but strangely I did get a real value when I tried ga:newUsers)

What is strange is that on analytics.google.com I get real values for Users pre-2016 dates.

Anybody knows what's wrong here? Was ga:users a substitute metric for some old deprecated one on august 2016? I read somewhere that once was a ga:visitors metric now deprecated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: - In 2014 Visits were changed to Sessions and Unique Visitors to Users. Following is a helpful read: https://www.e-nor.com/blog/google-analytics/google-analytics-new-labels-mystery-of-the-returning-visitors
- Also regarding new calculations used for User Metrics that apply to data after Sept 2016 https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered this same problem! If my request for ga:users has a start date before 23-Aug-2016 I get only zeros for users, though non-zero numbers are reported at analytics.google.com, and I can get ga:newUsers just fine.

I would say ga:newUsers is the most reasonable substitute, though it will always undercount users.

If you turn off the new calculation method (as described in the [support doc](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en) linked to by commenter Bronwyn V, above), you will get numbers for ga:users prior to 23-Aug-2016.